# Hide email field from moderator view on mobile site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, mobile-web

When viewing a user page on the full site, moderators (*but not SE Employees*) see a little "click to show" link in the email address field. Clicking this reveals the user's email address (obviously).

[image: Screenshot]

However, on the mobile site, when going to a user's page, their email address is already shown. (Sorry, no screenshot for this.)

I imagine that the reason the email address is hidden by default is to protect the user's privacy; so that moderators see that information *only* if they decide to contact that user. I feel that users should be afforded the same protection whether the moderator uses the full site or the mobile site.

Comment: I'm not sure why the email field is hidden. If it is a privacy issue in the sense that a mod should not see the email default , then yeah, it would be logical to be consistent. But if it is more like "another person can look over your shoulder", then that is less dangerous on mobile devices?

Comment: I agree with Nanne's second opinion. If it was really a privacy issue, it would be logged when a mod clicks on the show link.

Comment: @DoubleAA Not sure bout that. An email can reveal personally identifying info about a user. In general, a mod has a lot of tools that can help identify people, but it doesn't mean it's prudent to go poking around in there without reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was just a mistake waiting to happen, so it has now been implemented on mobile *and* the main sites for all personally-identifiable information on that page.

Per [Double AA's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122801/hide-email-field-from-moderator-view-on-mobile-site/187197#comment483633_122801), we're logging access to this data now as well.

Comment: 1: Awesome! 2: Oooooooh....

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10256257#10256257

Answer (score 2):

It seems this has been implemented for both the email and real name fields.

Comment: I was surprised to see real names now behind a link (and probably, err, generated a bunch of log entries while trying to figure out why that was happening).  I guess it makes sense though; just never thought about it before.